# Network share readonly for Java Application

Tags: windows, networking, network-shares, windows-server-2008-r2

We have a windows server with Windows 2008 R2 SP1. This server provides a network share, let's call it `Data`. The permissions are set to `Read/Write` for all domain users.

Multiple PCs (`PC1 to PC4`) in the local net have mapped this network share as drive letter `H:` using the same username `MyUser`.

In this network share there's an application folder for a specific Java Application. So each PC opens the application by opening the .exe (Let's say `H:\App\run-java-app.exe`)

On PC1 and PC2 (both Windows 7) the application runs fine.
On PC3 (Win 8.1) and PC4 (Win 7) the application opens but it can't write any files. Thus PC3 and 4 have **only read access**.

**Problem statement:**

Same Java Application on PC3 and 4 has only read access, on PC1 and 2 read/write.

**Debugging the problem:**

- Creating a file trough Windows Explorer works without an error. And e.g. Word can write into the folder on all PCs.
- All the PCs use the same User for connecting to the shared folder. I've already tried to remove the network share, reboot, and reconnect. No success.
- I've already removed the shared permissions on the server and recreated them. No success.
- Adding read/write permission for the user **Everyone** solves the problem
- I already wrote a simple Java application which creates a file and writes to it. This also worked on all PCs.

**Question:**

How can I debug the problem further? Is there a method to check how a file is accessed on the server?

PC3 and 4 can write to the network share if I'm using e.g. Word, but the Java Application has no write access.
It looks like only this specific Java Application has problems.

Answer (score 0):

Is it consisten? I mean, PC3 and PC4 are always the ones that have RO and the others RW? Could it be a file locking issue having others access before them?

PD: Can't yet comment so I have to "answer" with questions, sorry.

Comment: Yes, it's consistent. Only (and always) PC3 and PC4 are affected.